# Add a Bootstrap loading spinner to a modal body

Tags: javascript, html, bootstrap-modal

I have a bootstrap modal that loads a html table in the body. I want to add a spinner that shows before the html table loads and disappears after is loads.

This is my current attempt.

html

```
<div onload="myFunction()" class="modal-body"> 
    <div class="spinner-border text-primary" 
    id="spinner" role="status">
    <span class="sr-only">Loading...</span>
    </div>      
    <div id="table-to-update" class='table-to-update'></div>
</div>
```

JS

```
var myVar;

function myFunction() {
  myVar = setTimeout(showPage, 3000);
}

function showPage() {
  document.getElementById("spinner").style.display = "none";
  document.getElementById("table-to-update").style.display = "block";
}
```

[image: My attempt]

As you can see in the picture the spinner appears while the table is loading but when the table loads the spinner is still there.

Any ideas on how I can fix this?

Comment: What is BS, Is it swearing?

Comment: fixed to bootstrap

Comment: If you are using a true bootstrap modal, bootstrap's modal has a javascript function that you can use to open and close it. And using it you can add an event listener to when the modal has opened and shown (4.0 https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/modal/)